# Alternative to ftp_exec()?

Tags: php, ftp, zip

Is there any way to have one server call and execute a script on another server? I have tried ftp_exec(), but the server does not support it. Here is what I am trying to do.

Server 1 creates and uploads a zip file to Server 2. Server 2 then unzips and extracts the file.

Currently I have scheduled cron jobs at alternating times, one on each server in order to do this. Ideally I would like Server 1 to be able to do everything, sending a message to sever 2 telling it to unzip and extract the uploaded file.

Is it possible to do something on Server 1, like `exec(php ftp://user:password@server2/unzip.php)` ?

Is it maybe possible using CURL?

Comment: You need to do this over HTTP (or some other method, but HTTP is probably easiest) - does Server 2 have a PHP enabled web server on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FTP = File Transfer Protocol. It's not intended (and should never be used for) remote execution. If you need to trigger a remote script, use HTTP. It's easy enough to do

```
$stat = file_get_contents('http://example.com/unzip.php');
```

to invoke the remote PHP script to do the unzipping. If you need authentication on the URL, you can set up a [stream](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) or use [CURL](http://php.net/curl) instead.

Comment: FYI `user:pass@` syntax works in PHP with HTTP Basic auth (obviously, as long a `allow_url_fopen` is enabled).

Comment: I couldn't use http:// because the script I want to run is not in the webroot (so it's not publicly accessible)

When I move it to the webroot, `file_get_contents()` does work, but anyone can just type in the url and run the script now.

Comment: Just put a really basic hash on it `if ($_GET['pw'] != sha1('automatic')) die;`.

Comment: Will the resulting/extracted files be owned by the server? I'm trying to extract a zip file but wanted it so that the extracted files are owned by the ftp user, is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Does your sever support ssh or have you the ssh account?

You can run remote commands via ssh.

Comment: this would probably work too, but it seems a bit more complicated than necessary.